# Nested static classes initialized in wrong order?

Tags: c#, .net, debugging

There appears to be an issue with nested static classes being initialized before their parent. See the example below, I've included comments to indicate the order in which I expected things to get initialized/called, and the actual order. In this case I'm calling `Test1.Test2.GetName()`, so I expected the static classes to be initialized in this order: `Test1`, `Test2`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication1 {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            Console.WriteLine(Test1.Test2.GetName());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public static class Test1 {
        // Actual Order: 2; Expected: 1
        private static string Name = "Test1";
        public static List<string> Names { get; private set; }

        // Actual Order: 3; Expected: 2
        static Test1() {
            Test1.Names = new List<string>(new string[] {
                Test2.GetName()
            });
        }

        public static class Test2 {
            // Actual Order: 1; Expected: 3
            private static string Name = Test1.Name.ToString() + "_Test2";

            // Actual Order: 4; Expected: 4
            public static string GetName() {
                return Name.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I thought statics were initialized the first time a class was touched, but apparently touching a nested class doesn't first initialize the parent! This feels like a bug to me. It's doing this:

`Test2.Name` -> `Test1.Name` -> `Test1()` -> `Test2.GetName()` -> `Test2.Name`

So although `Test2.Name` is the entry point, in theory, it is not initialized by the time it's needed.

Comment: Covered well in [the literature](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx).  Quote: "The user has no control on when the static constructor is executed in the program".  In other words, the order is not "wrong", it is undefined.

Comment: It also says "is called automatically before the first instance is created or any static members are referenced" which is not true in this case as the nested static class is initialized first! I'm not expecting to have control, but I should be able to assume the order in which this would happen.

Comment: You should rely on initialization methods instead. That way you control the initialization. In worst case you can initialize them from a static constructor in Program.

Comment: That is what I did as a work-around but this still feels like a bug in the compiler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> A static constructor is called automatically to initialize the class before the first instance is created or any **static members** are referenced.

The issue is that a nested class is *not* a *static member* of its parent. It's a different class entirely. It has a `nested` [attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.typeattributes.aspx) but this is only for member visibility purposes.

From [ECMA-335](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf) (the CLI spec):

> **I.8.11.5 Nested type definitions**
>   A nested type definition is identical to a top-level type definition, with one exception: a top-level
>   type has a visibility attribute, while the visibility of a nested type is the same as the visibility of
>   the enclosing type.

Thus, the behavior is correct. The docs don't require the parent class to be initialized when calling a nested class. Anyway, you should note that nested public classes should be avoided, just like public fields, as this is not good encapsulation. Nested classes should mainly be used for implementation details, and hidden from the outside.

If a nested class requires its parent class to be initialized first, you can explicitly force it in its static constructor:

```
static Test2()
{
    RuntimeHelpers.RunClassConstructor(typeof(Test1).TypeHandle);
}
```

Here, the meaning is crystal clear.

But this won't make your example valid, as it has a circular dependency:

- The `Test1` static constructor calls `Test2.GetName()`, which means it will trigger the initialization of `Test2`
- The `Test2` static constructor (implicit) calls `Test1.Name.ToString() + "_Test2"`, which will trigger the initialization of `Test1`

Either way, it won't work, you have to fix that code.

Comment: Understood. Though I still would suggest that nested classes should initialize after their parent, though the relationship is basically meaningless. If there was a choice of order, it should be outer-to-inner. In my case it's just a couple nested static classes holding settings so I can do something like `Settings.UI.Something.SomeValue` -- not any serious work being done here, so it's a moot point. I just set the parent class to initialize the children in its static constructor and called it a day. Thanks!